# Output text file with ANSI encoding

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have XML file, which need to be converted as text file with encoding ANSI.

I tried the followings, but I am getting only the UTF-8 encoding:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="us-ascii"/>

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="us-ascii" method="text/plain"/>
```

Is there anyway to get the text file with ANSI encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is commonly called ANSI is in English-speaking environments technically "Windows-1252". You can try that in place of "us-ascii".

Comment: Hi @Minopret. When i use the Windows-1252 encoding, somefiles get converted but for some files I am facing the following issue and can't get the output. `Output character not available in this encoding (decimal 961)`. How these files could be converted? Hope this is because the special character present in the input.

Comment: @Senthil, Windows-1252 is an 8-bit encoding that does not contain that character, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c1/codepage_support.htm which lists code pages that contain the character (but of course then might not contain other characters that Windows-1252 contains). If you choose output method text then there are no escape mechanisms to render such characters that are not available in the choose encoding. You will have to choose an encoding that can represent all characters you need.